# Unable to compile code because deprecated framework

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am looking into an old code where there have have RxCocoa framework, when I compile the code, I see the error [image]

Comment: Use `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: You should either upgrade RxCocoa or downgrade RxSwift. They should both have the same version number.

Answer (score 0):

Variable (was) a part of RxCocoa, now it is deprecated.
Most probably you have diff versions of RxCocoa and RxSwift in as dependencies